# Keeping manually entered data side-by-side with pivot table data — row misalignment issue

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table (columns 1 and 2), and I also have manually inserted data (columns 3 and 4):

[image: Table1]

But when more data gets added to the pivot table, the manually entered columns won't follow "their" row, so the rows become misaligned like this:

[image: Table2]

I would need the table to behave so that when new data gets added to the pivot table, the manually inserted rows keep up with "their" row, like this:

[image: Table3]

I've looked around, tried to make it work, but couldn't find anything. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a row misalignment issue. Hand-entered data is static and will stay put as dynamical formula results or pivot tables are free to expand and contract.

One solution would be to make columns 3 and 4 part of the table from which you create the pivot.

Another would be to use a unique ID (perhaps the name field, if names are guaranteed to be unique) as a lookup key, and maintain columns 3 and 4 in another sheet together with the unique ID. You can then use a `vlookup()` formula to place columns 3 and 4 side-by-side with the pivot table.

Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought about making the columns part of the pivot, but that wouldn't help with how things are done here. The unique ID idea on the other hand, is just perfect.